# Bubble sort or aphabetical order

Tags: c#

The whole idea of this code is to convert string numbers into the numbers then to sum it and sort it in specific order. So I Have a class called "Sort" that takes a string "TabName" and int "TabCV" and in this method I want to sort list of that class by int "TabCV" but if the int is in both cases similiar then I want to sort it in aphabetical order. The problem is that I am getting an error called "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IOrderedEnumerable'"

```
class Sort
{
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public int TabCV { get; set; }
}

static List<Sort> Sorts(List<Sort> list)//Retarted Bubble sort
{
    Sort temp = new Sort();
    var tempList = new List<Sort>();
    for (int j = 0; j <= list.Count - 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].TabCV > list[i + 1].TabCV)
            {
                temp = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = list[i];
                list[i] = temp;
            }
            else if(list[i].TabCV == list[i + 1].TabCV)
            {
                tempList.Add(list[i + 1]);
                tempList.Add(list[i]);

                var tempTempList = tempList.OrderBy(x => x.TabName);

                list[i + 1] = tempTempList[1]; <= Here I am getting an error
                list[i] = tempTempList[0]; <= Here I am getting an error

                tempList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Before when I tried a little diffrent thing which looked like this It worked for first 3 exmaples then it was messed up again. (I think this approach is more retarded than what I am trying to do know but idk)

```
static List<Sort> Sorts(List<Sort> list)//Bubble sort retarted
{
    Sort temp = new Sort();
    var tempList = new List<Sort>();
    for (int j = 0; j <= list.Count - 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].TabCV > list[i + 1].TabCV)
            {
                temp = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = list[i];
                list[i] = temp;
            }
            else if(list[i].TabCV == list[i + 1].TabCV)
            {
                tempList.Add(list[i + 1]);
                tempList.Add(list[i]);

                tempList.OrderBy(x => x.TabCV.ToString());

                list[i + 1] = tempList[1];
                list[i] = tempList[0];

                tempList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Example of test cases : "103 123 4444 99 2000", "2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123"

Comment: OrderBy is a Linq expression. You var it, so you cannot see the actual type (and that's ok) but you should know that is not enumerated yet. You need to ToList or ToArray it before using it.  (You could of course not enumerate it upfront, but that would mean the values are ordered again on every access, which is very expensive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the whole bubble sorting, that does the list for you, just implement your sort logic:

```
public class Sort : IComparable<Sort> {

    public string? TabName { get; set; }
    
    public int TabCV { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Sort? other) {
        if (other is null) return 1;
        if (this.TabCV < other.TabCV) return -1;
        if (this.TabCV > other.TabCV) return 1;
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(this.TabName, other.TabName);
    }

}
```

and then call `list.Sort();` after filling it.

Comment: Maybe note that you've got nullable enabled, while the OP hasn't.